# Comparison with a range

Tags: c#, object-oriented

I'm developing a class to compare prices. For example, give me products which price are above 50 or under 50. Here's my API:

```
var indicator = new PriceIndicator(PriceComparison.Above, 50);
var actual = indicator.Apply(listOfProductPrices);
```

I managed to design my code for the operator Above and Under comparison:

```
public abstract class PriceComparison
{
    public static readonly UnderPriceComparison Under = new UnderPriceComparison();

    public static readonly AbovePriceComparison Above = new AbovePriceComparison();

    public abstract bool Evaluate(double price, double valueToCompare);
}

public class AbovePriceComparison : PriceComparison
{
    public override bool Evaluate(double price, double valueToCompare)
    {
        return price > valueToCompare;
    }
}

public class UnderPriceComparison : PriceComparison
{
    public override bool Evaluate(double price, double valueToCompare)
    {
        return price < valueToCompare;
    }
}


public class PriceIndicator : IBuyIndicator
{
    private readonly PriceComparison _comparison;
    private readonly int _value;

    public PriceIndicator(PriceComparison comparison, int value) 
    {
        _comparison = comparison;
        _value = value;
    }


    public IList<BuyOrder> Apply(IList<int> productPrices)
    {
        return productPrices.Where(price => _comparison.Evaluate(price, _value))
                            .Select(b => new BuyOrder(b))
                            .ToList();
    }
}
```

Now, I want to manage Range price. I want my API to look as simple as the one above. Ideally, it would be

```
var indicator = new PriceIndicator(PriceComparison.Range, 50, 100); // Here's the change
var actual = indicator.Apply(listOfProductPrices);
```

I don't know how I can design this. What I tried to do so far is to add another Evaluate method in `PriceComparison`, which takes three parameters: `double price, double left, double right`.  But then, my previous two methods have to implement it and will have to throw `IncorrectComparisonException` because they can only compare with one value. So I'm not really fan of this design.

Comment: Your code won't compile, there is no `Close` property on `int`. You should post (parts of) your real code, not something you didn't even bother compiling.

Comment: Also, never ever use `double` for prices, that's exactly what `decimal` is for.

Comment: @svick your answer looks so rude. I did remove the Close property from an edit, and you can see in modification historic that I did it but it doesn't appear. Then, the code I posted here is pretty much 98% part of my real code, except for the variable listOfProductPrices and I did take something like 30min to write my question and later re read it many time to fix some mistakes + the help of jamal who was the first to fix some gramatical error. Anyway, it was my first question on codereview, and your answer really hurt me. Then you say, I should use decimal instead of double for price, can you

Comment: please explain why so it could help me and other people without needed to have to search ourself on the web ? Anyway, I'm not interested by an answer to my code review anymore. I always take the time to post a clear question and there're people like you who says rude thing. It totally destroyed my work day. Thanks for your comment and the -1 by the way.

Comment: 1. I did not downvote your question. 2. From the history, it looks to me like the edit from Jamal overwrote the `Close` change, I tried to fix that now. I also voted to reopen the question. 3. You really should post your real code, it's hard to review code that doesn't make sense and some suggestions based on the altered code might not be applicable to your real code. 4. If you really aren't interested in answers anymore, feel free to delete the question.

Comment: Regarding `decimal`: the short version is that `double` is a *binary* floating point type, which means it can't represent numbers like `0.1` exactly (and so for example `0.1 + 0.7 != 0.8`). On the other hand, `decimal` is a *decimal* floating point type, so it can represent decimal fractions exactly.

Comment: @JohnSmith: Questions automatically receive a -1 upon closing.  As for svick's compiler note, all code should be compiled before posting.  This site is only for working code, but underlying errors not found by you nor the compiler _are_ okay even if found by someone else.  Seeing as svick fixed the issue, I'll put in my reopen vote as well.

Comment: @svick tell me that you're sorry for being rude and I'll accept my question to be reopened for answers.

Comment: @Jamal Thanks Jamal for your kind and complete answer, I will now always compile my code before posting a new question on codereview.com. It's really different here than in stackoverflow, overthere I always put some half uncompiled code and people never complain. I guess, it was obvious we need to put more effort here as it's about judging the quality of code and people may need to test our code in order to provide the most accurate solution.

Comment: @JohnSmith: Right.  Over there, _errors are solved_.  Here, _design is improved_.  I'm glad I've helped.

Comment: @svick btw, I tried in unit test 0.1 + 0.7, and you're right, it's not equal to 0.8 ? Why you say it can't represent 0.1 exactly ? What I found on the web is that the main difference between decimal and double is precision and as you said one is binary floating and the other one is decimal floating. Still I don't get why its not equal 0.1+0.7 != 0.8, why it can't represent accurately these values in binary ?

Comment: You can't represent 1/3 exactly in decimal fractions, you have to write something like 0.33333. It's very similar with 1/10 and binary fractions. The difference is that you don't have tenths, hundredths, etc., but you have halves, quarters, eights and so on. So, 3/8 can be represented exactly as 0.011, but 1/10 can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go. I made `Range` inclusive only, but it's easy to modify. I also extracted a few interfaces for easy unit testing and use `IEnumerable<T>` instead of `IList<T>`.

```
public interface IPriceComparison
{
    bool Evaluate(decimal price, params decimal[] valuesToCompare);
}

public abstract class PriceComparison : IPriceComparison
{
    private static readonly IPriceComparison under = UnderPriceComparison.Create();

    private static readonly IPriceComparison above = AbovePriceComparison.Create();

    private static readonly IPriceComparison range = RangePriceComparison.Create();

    public static IPriceComparison Under
    {
        get
        {
            return under;
        }
    }

    public static IPriceComparison Above
    {
        get
        {
            return above;
        }
    }

    public static IPriceComparison Range
    {
        get
        {
            return range;
        }
    }

    public abstract bool Evaluate(decimal price, params decimal[] valuesToCompare);
}

public sealed class AbovePriceComparison : PriceComparison
{
    private AbovePriceComparison()
    {
    }

    public static IPriceComparison Create()
    {
        return new AbovePriceComparison();
    }

    public override bool Evaluate(decimal price, params decimal[] valuesToCompare)
    {
        return (valuesToCompare == null) || (valuesToCompare.Length != 1) || (price > valuesToCompare[0]);
    }
}

public sealed class UnderPriceComparison : PriceComparison
{
    private UnderPriceComparison()
    {
    }

    public static IPriceComparison Create()
    {
        return new UnderPriceComparison();
    }

    public override bool Evaluate(decimal price, params decimal[] valuesToCompare)
    {
        return (valuesToCompare == null) || (valuesToCompare.Length != 1) || (price < valuesToCompare[0]);
    }
}

public sealed class RangePriceComparison : PriceComparison
{
    private RangePriceComparison()
    {
    }

    public static IPriceComparison Create()
    {
        return new RangePriceComparison();
    }

    public override bool Evaluate(decimal price, params decimal[] valuesToCompare)
    {
        return (valuesToCompare == null)
            || (valuesToCompare.Length != 2)
            || ((price > valuesToCompare[0]) && (price < valuesToCompare[1]));
    }
}

public interface IBuyOrder
{
    int Price
    {
        get;
    }
}

public sealed class BuyOrder : IBuyOrder
{
    private readonly int price;

    private BuyOrder(int price)
    {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public static IBuyOrder Create(int price)
    {
        return new BuyOrder(price);
    }

    public int Price
    {
        get
        {
            return this.price;
        }
    }
}

public interface IBuyIndicator
{
    IEnumerable<IBuyOrder> Apply(IEnumerable<int> productPrices);
}

public sealed class PriceIndicator : IBuyIndicator
{
    private readonly IPriceComparison comparison;

    private readonly decimal[] values;

    private PriceIndicator(IPriceComparison comparison, params decimal[] values)
    {
        if (comparison == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("comparison");
        }

        this.comparison = comparison;
        this.values = values;
    }

    public static IBuyIndicator Create(IPriceComparison comparison, params decimal[] values)
    {
        return new PriceIndicator(comparison, values);
    }

    public IEnumerable<IBuyOrder> Apply(IEnumerable<int> productPrices)
    {
        return productPrices.Where(price => this.comparison.Evaluate(price, this.values))
            .Select(BuyOrder.Create)
            .ToList();
    }
}
```